# PLSQL-0043 - cannot be v_day into select / fetch

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a PLSQL code to get current day name using PLSQL and assigning it to variable

**Code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ABC_STORE
(
    v_day varchar2
)
AS
BEGIN
     select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DAY') into v_day from dual;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_day);
END;
```

**Error :**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add al least clause OUT for value v_day:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ABC_STORE
(
    v_day IN OUT varchar2
)
AS
BEGIN
     select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'DAY') into v_day from dual;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_day);
END;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the query, because PL/SQL has an assignment  operator `:=`.

You also don't need `dbms_output` if the requirement is just to bring back the day name.

Also, the `'DAY'` format element includes blank padding by default (e.g. `SUNDAY`   ), so `'fmDAY'` provides the expected result `SUNDAY`. If it doesn't need to be all capitals, you can use `'fmDay'`.

```
create or replace procedure day_name
    ( v_day out varchar2 )
as
begin
    v_day := to_char(sysdate,'fmDay');
end day_name;
```

Just to add, if you are checking the day name as part of some business logic (for example, a batch step should not run at the weekend), you will also need to specify a date language to avoid the situation where you are checking for 'Sunday' and the procedure is called from a support desk in Paris and returns 'Dimanche'. You would do this using (for example - substitute any language you want)

```
to_char(sysdate,'fmDay','nls_date_language=English')
```

(Of course, if you were just checking for the weekend you would only need to get the English three letter abbreviation and check whether it's `like 'S%'`, but this is not what you asked for. I mention it because I have seen production errors caused by poorly handled day name checks, and as a result I use it as an interview question, which it turns out very few candidates can answer.)